# AWS Code Commit Cross Account IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

I have two AWS accounts:

```
DEV:  111111111111
PROD: 999999999999
```

I created an a code commit repo in the prod account called `prodRepo`.

What I want to do is allow an ec2 instance on the `DEV` and `PROD` account to have read-only access to this repo. So `git clone`, `git pull`, etc...

I can do this easily on my `PROD` account using the following IAM instance profile called `codecommit-tester`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "codecommit:BatchGetRepositories",
        "codecommit:Get*",
        "codecommit:GitPull",
        "codecommit:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:999999999999:prodRepo"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Trust Relationship policy is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

Then I use the aws credentials helpers in the git config to perform read-only git operations without having to store credentials on my machine (it gets the credentials for code commit from the instance metadata).

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[credential]
    helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

The problem I am having is creating an the IAM policy/role on the `DEV` account to do the same thing as the `PROD` account. Here is what I tried.

I edited the Trust Relationship on the `PROD` account to trust the DEV account:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
}
```

Now I think this means the `DEV` account can assume this role. On the `DEV` account I created these IAM policies attached to a role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:BatchGetRepositories",
                "codecommit:Get*",
                "codecommit:GitPull",
                "codecommit:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:999999999999:prodRepo"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/codecommit-tester"
    }
}
```

I use the credentials helper on the DEV account after launching an ec2 instance using this IAM instance profile and I get this error when performing a `git clone`:

```
$ git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/prodRepo
Cloning into 'prodRepo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/prodRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

So what did I miss in the IAM roles/policies on the `DEV` to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need iam role in **dev** which you mention (On the DEV account I created these IAM policies attached to a role) .... have not tried with instance cross account assume role..
but if you can create new IAM role in prod account with

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/codecommit-tester"
    }
]
}
```

and trust relation would be something like

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

and just assume new IAM ARN in dev ec2 role.

Comment: Yup, this helped. Thanks!